# html5 checker compilation

Tags: java, python, html, symfony, liipfunctionaltestbundle

I would like to use html5 validator from `LiipFunctionalTestBundle` in my Symfony2 project.
So, I followed instructions on bundle's github page, but I got this error during python build:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './syntax/relaxng/datatype/java/dist/html5-datatypes.jar'

indeed, there is a "dist" folder under that path, but it's empty (no files inside).
I also tried to download file from daisy-pipeline, but it's deleted after running python build again

I'm using Java 1.7.0_04 on Ubuntu x64

Comment: You need to install JDK, not only JRE. That is because you need java compiler.

Comment: You can also use the default validator `https://validator.nu/`. Can you please add your configuration and the code which call the validator in your question?

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> You need to install JDK, not only JRE. That is because you need java compiler.